# Problems with curses.h on OSX Lion

Tags: c++, osx-lion, curses

I'm trying to use `curses.h` library for the first time, but no matter which function I call I still get an error that says

> -Symbol(s) not found for Architecture x86_64-

Am i missing some kind of initialization? This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include<time.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ncurses.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
    string a,b = ("...");
    WINDOW *mywindow;
    mywindow = initscr();
    refresh();
    cout<<"Inserisci la frase da passare in coolprint ->";
    cin>>a;
    coolprint(a);
    cout<<endl;
    hackprint(a);
    coolprint(b);
    cout<<endl;
    slideprint(a);
    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I didn't post all the functions but if i take out the calls from `curses.h` and use `system("clear")` instead, everything works fine.
It's probably some really stupid issue, but i'm kind a newbie with c++.
Hope somebody can help
Thanks.

Comment: Mixing standard stream input/output (`cin`/`cout`) with curses is not recommended. Use one or the other, but not both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are not linking the ncurses library`/usr/lib/libncurses.dylib` into your program...

It is not clear how you are trying to compile the program (makefile, command line, Xcode), so I cannot advise further, but it should be readily done...

In Xcode:

1. In the project navigator, select your project
2. Select your target
3. Select the 'Build Phases' tab
4. Open 'Link Binaries With Libraries' expander
5. Click the '+' button
6. Select your framework (in your case look for libncurses under your SDK)
7. (optional) Drag and drop the added framework to the 'Frameworks' group

Note: OSX supports unicode very well, however many open-source ./configure scripts choose settings that prevent ncurses from displaying unicode characters.

Comment: ijust tryed to link libncruses but the compiler says that it cannot find it. Is it possible that is only a matter of mixing code for I\O?

Comment: don't think so, that should produce some kind of runtime error, possibly, but not a symbol not found when linking. what is the exact error message? (btw, I added steps for adding a framework)

Comment: thanks for the small tutorial, now the program is compiled, the problem was the framework, but I'm still getting some some weird behave while it's running. Probably it's just a matter of studying more the curses lib... thanks you've been very helpfull at least now i can start!

Comment: thanks to have helped! don't forget to upvote/accept this answer if it was helpful...

Answer (score 1):

use gcc in terminal:

-> gcc filename.c -lncurses

-> ./a.out